# I am using following code to save data on firebase .but data dont save in firebase , how can I fix it?

Tags: android, firebase

```java
creat_acount_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.creat_acountID);

creat_acount_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String name=username.getText().toString().trim();
        String em=email.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass=password.getText().toString().trim();
        final String phoneNum=phone.getText().toString().trim();
        final  String loc=location.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc=description.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(loc)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(em)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc))
        {
            mProgress.setMessage("Creating Acount");
            mProgress.show();

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em,pass)
                 .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    if (authResult!=null)
                    {
                        String userid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference curentuserDB=mDatabaseReference.child(userid);
                        curentuserDB.child("UserName").setValue(username);
                        curentuserDB.child("phone").setValue(phoneNum);
                        curentuserDB.child("location").setValue(loc);
                        curentuserDB.child("Description").setValue(desc);

                        mProgress.dismiss();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this,Post.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you check by adding addOnSuccessListener?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding on failure listener like this and output the error if it exist:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em,pass).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            //Successful
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                String userid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                DatabaseReference curentuserDB=mDatabaseReference.child(userid);
                        curentuserDB.child("UserName").setValue(username);
                        curentuserDB.child("phone").setValue(phoneNum);
                        curentuserDB.child("location").setValue(loc);
                        curentuserDB.child("Description").setValue(desc);

                        mProgress.dismiss();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this,Post.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
            }
            //Error
            else {                
                Log.d("Error", Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getLocalizedMessage()));
            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Log.d("Error", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
        });
```

Comment: It not allow me to use addOnfailureListener ??